# Regasm through Wise installer

Tags: vb6, installation, regasm, wise

I have a Visual Basic 6 program, which needs to use a C# dll. On my developement environment(XP) I can do manual RegAsm xxxx.dll /tlb:xxx.tlb /codebase and It works fine.

Now, I need to install this program on target machines- which on most cases are Win 7, 8.1 and 10, using Wise Installer v1.5( which does not have any RegAsm capability).

Does anyone know if there is a way I can call an API call or something from my vb program to register the C# dll, and create .tlb file, automatically?

Any help is much appreciated,

Comment: Since regasm needs to be run with administrator rights, that means in order to run regasm from your app, you'd need run your app with admin rights, which is generally a bad idea.  I'm not familiar with the Wise installer, but installers generally have the capability to run a batch file, so you could create a batch file that would perform the regasm and have the installer run that.

Comment: Many can also run custom actions implemented in VBScript, as a C DLL entrypoint, etc.

Comment: It could be time to look for an up-to-date install package...

Comment: Have you tried to invoke the `Shell` command with using the command line arguments to RegAsm?